# double-precision numbers in inline assembly (GCC, IA-32)

Tags: c, assembly

I'm just starting to learn assembly and I want to round a floating-point value using a specified rounding mode. I've tried to implement this using `fstcw`, `fldcw`, and `frndint`.

Right now I get a couple of errors:

```
~ $ gc a02p
gcc -Wall -g a02p.c -o a02p
a02p.c: In function `roundD':
a02p.c:33: error: parse error before '[' token
a02p.c:21: warning: unused variable `mode'
~ $
```

I'm not sure if I am even doing this right at all. I don't want to use any predefined functions. I want to use GCC inline assembly.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRECISION           3
#define RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT   10

// floating point rounding modes: IA-32 Manual, Vol. 1, p. 4-20
typedef enum {
ROUND_NEAREST_EVEN =    0 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_MINUS_INF =       1 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_PLUS_INF =        2 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT,
ROUND_TOWARD_ZERO =     3 << RND_CTL_BIT_SHIFT
} RoundingMode;

double roundD (double n, RoundingMode roundingMode)
{

short c;
short mode = (( c & 0xf3ff) | (roundingMode));


asm("fldcw    %[nIn] \n"
    "fstcw    %%eax  \n"             // not sure why i would need to store the CW
    "fldcw    %[modeIn] \n"
    "frndint            \n"
    "fistp    %[nOut]          \n"


     : [nOut]  "=m"          (n)
     : [nIn]   "m"           (n)
     : [modeIn]  "m"         (mode)

     );

 return n;


}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
double  n = 0.0;


if (argc > 1)
    n = atof(argv[1]);

printf("roundD even %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_NEAREST_EVEN));
printf("roundD down %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_MINUS_INF));
printf("roundD up   %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_PLUS_INF));
printf("roundD zero %.*f = %.*f\n",
       PRECISION, n, PRECISION, roundD(n, ROUND_TOWARD_ZERO));

return 0;
}
```

Am I even remotely close to getting this right?

Comment: One of your classmates has already asked this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249917/working-with-double-precision-numbers-in-inline-assembly-gcc-ia-32

Comment: There's no point using `fstcw` right after clobbering the old control word with `fldcw` with a constant.  You also never load `n` into the x87 FPU.  Inline asm is a horrible way to do this, so I won't take the time to write up a full answer.  Just use `lrint(n)` or something.

Answer (score 0):

A better process is to write a simple function that rounds a floating point value.  Next, instruct your compiler to print an assembly listing for the function.  You may want to put the function in a separate file.

This process will show you the calling and exiting conventions used by the compiler.  By placing the function in a separate file, you won't have to build other files.  Also, it will give you the opportunity to replace the C language function with an assembly language function.

Although inline assembly is supported, I prefer to replace an entire function in assembly language and not use inline assembly (inline assembly isn't portable, so the source will have to be changed when porting to a different platform).

Answer (score 0):

GCC's inline assembler syntax is arcane to say the least, and I do not claim to be an expert, but when I have used it I used [this howto guide](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html). In all examples all template markers are of the form %n where n is a number, rather then the %[ttt] form that you have used.

I also note that the line numbers reported in your error messages do not seem to correspond with the code you posted.  So I wonder if they are in fact for this exact code?

Comment: The `%[identifier]` usage seems to be correct. It makes for more readable code. Rather than `%#` you can use the identifier. Both work equally well, one is more readable. One other advantage is that you can reorder the constraints and not worry about renumbering all the references in the template.